# Disappearing navigation at larger screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have some navigation html that I am trying to make responsive. I have succeeded in getting the hamburger menu to appear at a screen size of less than 1050px and it toggles the menu on and off. The problem is that if you don't close the hamburger menu before making the screen bigger, the nav menu is stuck in display: none mode and doesn't display. So it looks like the navigation suddenly goes missing. I thought that the normal css would engage at larger screen size but maybe because the property was set in a script it lingers. Can anyone help me get around this. I'm fairly new to responsive design.

html:

```
<nav>
<div class="navigation">
    <a href="/index.html"> <img class="nav-img" src="/incl/image.png"> </a>

    <button id="mobile" type="button" onclick="toggleFunction()">
          <img src="/incl/menu.png" width="35px" height="35px" alt="menu">
    </button>

    <ul id="nav-list">
        <li> <a href="/proposer/">Proposer</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="/cda/">Archive</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="/ciao/">Data<br/>Analysis</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="/cal/">Instruments and<br/>Calibration</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="/public/">For The<br/>Public</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div></nav>

<script>
    function toggleFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById('nav-list');

        if (x.style.display === 'block') {
            x.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            x.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
</script>
```

css:

```
#nav-list {
list-style-type: none;
padding-top: 30px;
padding-right: 20px;
margin: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
display: inline-table;
float: right;
}

#nav-list li {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
padding: 0px 15px;
margin: 0px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 110%;
font-size: 1.3em;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
}

#mobile {
display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1050px) {
.nav-img {
    margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#mobile {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
    padding: 5px;
}

#nav-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    float: none
}

#nav-list li {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    line-height: 110%;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to resolve this is by [toggling a class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) on the `#nav-list` element.

With this change, the class only has meaning in the CSS in the mobile media query, where it will change `#nav-list` to `display: block`. The class won't effect screens greater than 1050px regardless of whether it's toggled.

```js
function toggleFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById('nav-list');
  x.classList.toggle('show');
}
```

```css
#nav-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-table;
  float: right;
}

#nav-list li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 110%;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#mobile {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1050px) {
  .nav-img {
    margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
  }

  #mobile {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
    padding: 5px;
  }

  #nav-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    float: none
  }

  /* show navigation based on class */
  #nav-list.show {
    display: block;
  }

  #nav-list li {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    line-height: 110%;
    font-size: 1em;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="navigation">
    <a href="/index.html"> <img class="nav-img" src="/incl/image.png"> </a>

    <button id="mobile" type="button" onclick="toggleFunction()">
          <img src="/incl/menu.png" width="35px" height="35px" alt="menu">
    </button>

    <ul id="nav-list">
      <li> <a href="/proposer/">Proposer</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="/cda/">Archive</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="/ciao/">Data<br/>Analysis</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="/cal/">Instruments and<br/>Calibration</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="/public/">For The<br/>Public</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this with CSS:

```
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1056px) {

    #nav-list{
     display: none;
     }
```